# For which values of step size is LMS filter stable?

Tags: adaptive-filters, lms

For which values of step size $\alpha$ is LMS filter stable? I Wikipedia [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Convergence_and_stability_in_the_mean) on this question is incorrect.

For data sampled from zero-centered Gaussian in $d$-dimensions with identity covariance, we can show that LMS filter converges with probability 1 iff $\alpha<\alpha_c$ where

$d=1, \alpha_c\approx 2.4212495210$, [source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272402/tricky-findroot-nexpectation-problem), wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Convergence_and_stability_in_the_mean) predicts $\alpha_c=0.6667$

$d=2, \alpha_c\approx 0.937087$, derived [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430781/range-of-a-such-that-w-leftarrow-w-a-x-langle-w-x-rangle-converges-almos/430790?_gl=1*1crhiag*_ga*MjE5NzQ0ODg5LjE2NTAzMjYxNDU.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3ODk5Nzg5MC4zOTMuMS4xNjc5MDAzNTc2LjAuMC4w#430790)

Is anything known about range of convergent step sizes for any other cases?

Here is Python [simulation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t-BwH7biXFApGOmD9xPc0WVbLAlf_Rx8?usp=sharing)

You can see that mean diverges, but any single trajectory converges with probability 1.

[image]

---

The problem of LMS filter stability is equivalent to asking for which values of $\alpha$ following product converges with probability 1.

$$(I-\alpha x_1 x_1^T)(I-\alpha x_2 x_2^T)(I-\alpha x_3 x_3^T)\cdots$$

where $x_i$ are sampled IID from some distribution.

This is equivalent to computing Lyapunov exponent $\lambda$ for random variable $(I-\alpha x_i x_i^T)$, and asking for $\alpha$ such that $\lambda$ is negative. Lyapunov exponent is complicated to compute, so may need some cheap upper bound.

---

Standard theory predicts divergence of the mean for $\alpha>\frac{2}{\operatorname{Tr}(R)}$, however this is unconnected to real life performance because this kind of multiplicative process can have infinite mean despite being convergent with probability $1$. For instance for $x$ coming from standard normal, for $\alpha=1$, the process has infinite mean, yet 100% of trajectories converge.

This can be seen as follows:

Let $$x_t\sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$$

LMS update at time $t$ is the following

$$w_{t}=(1-\alpha x_i^2)w_{t-1}$$

After $t$ steps we have

$$w_t=w_0\prod_{i=1}^{t-1} (1-\alpha x_t^2)$$

$$\log w_t^2 = \log w_0^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}\log(1-2\alpha x_t^2+x_t^4)$$

We have a sum of IID random variables, so $\log w_t^2$ converges to Gaussian by Central Limit Theorem, and the original process converges with high probability if the mean of log transformed variable is negative, ie

$$E[\log(1-2\alpha x_t^2+x_t^4)]<0$$

Solving this equation gives $\alpha < 2.421249$. The mean of $w_t$ diverges to infinity for every $\alpha>2/3$, yet this divergence appears impossible to observe in practice - it requires being able to simulate zero probability trajectories

Comment: By "for any other cases", do you mean $d > 2$?

Comment: Or maybe on a different distribution. Just want to know anything relevant that will help me select step size that is guaranteed to converge

Comment: Why do you say that the Wikipedia information is incorrect? The result is a well-known result.  I'm wondering if the formulations are different, giving the differing results. Do you have a formulation of the problem that lays out all the definitions?

Comment: This result follows if you consider convergence of the mean. However, this is misleading because LMS is heavy-tailed. For LMS on standard normal $x$ with step-size $1$, the mean diverges to infinity, yet you converge for every initial condition with probability $1$. I came across this when trying to debug why my LMS experiments were all converging for this step size. Convergence in probability is what matters in practice

Comment: Added a section with analysis for standard normal, and why $2/Tr$ result is misleading in that case

Comment: BTW, this nice tutorial [summarizes](http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/pubs/pdf/ajp58p267.pdf) the issue, "The basic message is that numerical estimates from realistic scale simulations of a random multiplicative process have no relation to true average value"

Comment: FYI, @-less notifications don't work with >1 responder under a given post, so nobody was notified of your last 3 comments.

Comment: Aha, got it. It's interesting that it's a well known result, given that it's a factor of 3.6 off from value observed in practice. Perhaps the reason is that this mismatch shrinks for higher dimensions, so in high-d, the Trace formula becomes a useful proxy @PeterK.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks for the explanation! Very interesting.